# JAR file is not read even though added in class path

Tags: java, linux, shell, classpath

I have a shell script which runs a java class presnet in /opt/mydir/ directory. In this script I am adding the class file along with few other jar files to the java classpath.
Ex:

```
/usr/bin/java -cp "/opt/mydir"
```

When the script is run, the java .class file fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/internal/altsite
```

The com.inetrnal.altsite comes from an external jar, and is also present in the same classpath as the main class file.

If i add the name of the jar explicitly to the classpath, the shell script runs successfully without any error. Ex:

```
/usr/bin/java -cp "/opt/mydir:/opt/mydir/altsite.jar:"
```

The directory structor is as follows:

```
-/opt
---mydir/
-------runner.class,altsite.jar,jose4j.jar
```

Comment: AFIK, if your main function is in a jar file, you have to list this jar file inside the `-cp`, and not just the directory.

Comment: This is exactly how it’s supposed to behave.  From [the documentation of the java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html): “--class-path classpath, -classpath classpath, or -cp classpath — A list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files.”  Each classpath entry needs to be a single archive file.  (Use of unarchived directories is actually pretty rare, when not running in an IDE.)

Comment: @VGR yes the classpath has only the jar file and there is no other file archived in the jar itslef.

Comment: Maybe I wasn’t clear:  each entry in a classpath must be a hierarchy of packages and classes.  A directory containing .jar files is *not* a valid classpath entry and will be ignored.